# How can I find the url after i use 'git clone' to clone a repository

Tags: git

I use the 'git clone' to clone a repository from an URL to a local directory and now I forget the URL of that repository that I clone from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all your remotes:

`git remote show`

Then just pick the one you want (I assume it's `origin`):

`git remote show origin`

This also shows the remote branches and which branches are being tracked.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the branches with:

`git branch -va`

then for a remote branch, you can do:

`git remote show <remote-branch-name>`

`git help remote` and `git help branch` provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote -v` will show your remotes with the URLs you're pushing to and pulling from.

Comment: after executing this command it gives error
"unknown switch `v'"